# how to keep date as the uk standard but still input to database correct

Tags: php, jquery, date

I am trying to complete adding a date to my database I have a jQuery datapicker on my form but it adds a date like this `M - d - y` which my database doesn't accept. I need to add something to change the date before adding to the data base.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

I cant work out where I need to add this too any idea's

```
<?php include('connect2.php'); ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/jquery-ui.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/jquery-ui.theme.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/jquery.timepicker.css">




<body>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>index.php</title>
</head>

<body>

<pre>
    <?php

    if (isset ($_POST['submit'] )) {



    /*$query = "INSERT INTO visitors (firstname, lastname, time, date, email, staff) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]', '$_POST[lastname]', '$_POST[time]', '$_POST[date]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[staff]')";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    }*/


        $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO visitors (firstname, lastname, time, date, email, staff) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :time, :date, :email, :staff)");

        $statement->execute(array(


            "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],

            "lastname"  => $_POST['lastname'],

            "time" => $_POST['time'],

            "date" => $_POST['date'],

            "email" => $_POST['email'],

            "staff" => $_POST['staff'],

        ));
    }

    ?>


</pre>


    <h1>Navigation</h1>

<form action="index.php" method="post" >

    <p>
    <label>firstame: </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" size="50" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="">
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>lastname: </label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" size="50" placeholder="Enter Last Name" value="">
    </P>

    <p>
    <label>date: </label>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" size="50" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="">
    </P>

    <p>
    <label>email: </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" " size="50" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="">
    </P>

    <p>
    <label>time: </label>
    <input type="num" id="timer" name="time" size="50" placeholder="Enter First Name" value=""> 
    </p>

    <p>
    <label>staff: </label>
    <input type="text" name="staff" size="50" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="">  
    </p>

    <p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="">Add Apointment</button>
    </p>

    </form>

    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryui/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });

                $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#timer").timepicker();

                });

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it here:

```
$statement->execute(array(


        "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],

        "lastname"  => $_POST['lastname'],

        "time" => $_POST['time'],

        "date" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['date'])),

        "email" => $_POST['email'],

        "staff" => $_POST['staff'],

    ));
```

**EDIT**

Actually you should do the date conversion like this:

```
"date" => DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $_POST['date'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
```

Since you need to specify which format you're converting the date from, to make sure you do the conversion properly.

Comment: Thank you Sir you have helped a lot.

Comment: @RyanBaker please see my updated answer to get the correct conversion method. Also, if the answer worked for you, please upvote/mark it as accepted.

Comment: hello tryed the new code but it didnt work caaame up with this error- 
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\usayvisitors\index.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\usayvisitors\index.php on line 47

Comment: Which php version are you  using?